# Is it possible to grab a value from an input, and pass it in the params of a ruby link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I have a input fields, and if the user changes an input, I want it to reflect on the next page.

This is what the input looks like:

```
<input value="<%= @premium_discount.round %>" class="store_pricing_text_box store_gold" id="pro">
```

And then the link to go to the next page already passes a ruby param of the current`item`, but I'd also like to pass the value in the input with id `pro`

```
<%= link_to "I want this!", new_purchase_path(item_id: @item.id), class: "btn_primary" %>
```

I thought doing inline jQuery might be the solution - but that doesn't seem to work in a ruby line. Any other thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could add another a `class` (or an `id`) to the `link_to` and a `click` event to append the extra parameters; for example:

```
<%= link_to "I want this!", new_purchase_path(item_id: @item.id), class: "btn_primary my-link" %>

<script>
  $('.my-link').click(function() {
    $(this).attr("href", this.href + "&pro=" + $('#pro').val());
  });
</script>
```

Notice the added `my-link` class which is used by *jQuery* to detect the click on the link and add the `pro` attribute at the end.